# What do you call an iterator that returns the current, previous and next siblings of each node of a list?

Tags: data-structures, naming, iterator

What do you call an iterator that given a list `[a, b, c]`, returns an object of the form `{ prev, curr, next }` for each iteration?

e.g, (*? === `undefined`*)

```
{ prev: ?, curr: a, next: b }
{ prev: a, curr: b, next: c }
{ prev: b, curr: c, next: ? }
```

I thought `tuples`, but I am used to think that a *tuple* is usually a 2-item list so I am undecided.

---

> *EDIT*: *Triples* could work, but I was also wondering if there is any mention of this type of structures in the literature. I am familiar with linked lists, but this is different.
>
> *EDIT* 2: Here is the generator implementation in JavaScript.

```
  /**
    @syntax
    Parsec.prototype.tuples([a, b, c])
      { prev: ?, curr: a, next: b }
      { prev: a, curr: b, next: c }
      { prev: b, curr: c, next: ? }
    @param {Array|String} list List to iterate.
    @param {Object} [last] Define to use as the last value.
    @param {Object} [prev] Define to use as the first prev value.
    @param {Object} [curr] Define to use as the first curr value.
  */
  function* tuples(list, last, prev, curr) {
    for (let next of list) {
      if (curr !== undefined) yield { prev, curr, next /* add last here? */}
      prev = curr
      curr = next
    }
    yield { prev, curr, last }
  }
```

Comment: `tuple` doesn't mean two items specifically; it can be any number. A two-item `tuple` is a `pair`.

Comment: @RussellBorogove True, but it's often used to refer to two items, but in the end you can see I went with tuples anyway.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I don't know whether this is correct (probably isn't), but I believe `tuple` would be better written as `t-uple` where the `t` references the number of elements. At least, this is what we (Italians) do when using them in maths. We say `n-upla` to mean a "tuple" (ordered finite sequence) of `n` elements. The term *may* have been born like that where, for some reason, the name of the parameter was often `t`. So, no, `tuple`s are definitely not only (nor most often) used for 2 elements.

Comment: Recommended reading: **[On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6582/22815)**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apart from *triple* (which only means "we have three values") and *node* (which has been suggested by [manlio](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/283591/33157)), I can suggest the following alternatives:

## Sliding window

It looks like you always have a window of three consecutives elements in the list. This is the most appropriate name IMHO according to your situation.

That structure does not allow to easily navigate the list in terms of `prev`, `next` pointers, however (maybe it is intentional).
If you want to navigate the data-structure, you might want to call it a *node* (like in doubly-linked lists, as manlio said) or a *cursor*, which is a slightly better name that conveys the iterative capabilities of the object.

## Cursor

Iterators in Ada are built upon a so-called `Cursor` type, which encapsulates the position of an iterator inside a structure, along with `Next` and `Previous` operations.

See for example [Gem #127](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-127-iterators-in-ada-2012-part-1/) or the [Rationale for Ada 2005](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-8-2.html).

## Zipper

You question originally reminded me of [**Zippers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29) which are construct  usually found with purely functional data-structures. They allow to iterate over a structure while keeping enough context to navigate it.

For example, a list zipper would contain the reversed list of previous elements (Prefix), Current element and the usual Tail list:

```
(Prefix,Current,Tail)
```

It is easy to build a zipper for the next element in constant time:

```
(cons(Current,Prefix),head(Tail),tail(Tail))
```

Or, a zipper for the previous element in constant time:

```
(tail(Prefix),head(Prefix),cons(Current,Tail))
```

Of course, the cost of this approach is that you are manipulating two lists instead of one (during the lifetime of the iterator/zipper). Contrary to doubly-linked lists, you don't have to mutate your data-structures.

Your structure is clearly *not* a zipper, but it shared enough similarities with them that I thought it would be interesting to write about them.

Comment: 'Sliding window' have traits to 'convolution' which is related to 'fold' in the functional programming world. Whats funny though is the term convolution is a french translation from the word 'faltung' used by german mathematicians...faltung, fold, the array is folding on himself like the convolutions of the Amazon river. But that are mostly etymology convolutions. ;)

Answer (score 10):

In Scala, this is called a *sliding window*:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).sliding(2).foreach(println)
// List(1, 2)
// List(2, 3)
// List(3, 4)
// List(4, 5)
```

As opposed to *grouped* when the elements don't overlap:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).grouped(2).foreach(println)
// List(1, 2)
// List(3, 4)
// List(5)
```

In Ruby, it is called *cons*:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each_cons(2).to_a
# => [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

and the other one is called *slice*:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each_slice(2).to_a
# => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]
```

Note: in your case, the window starts before the first element and ends after the last, whereas in Ruby and Scala it starts *at* the first element and ends at the last, but that's just an arbitrary API design choice, and probably shouldn't affect the name.

I think "cons" (for "consecutive") is an unfortunate choice of name, because it clashes with the well-established term "cons" for "construct", as in Lisp and other functional languages. I like "sliding window" or "sliding view" much better.

Answer (score 5):

A tuple is a finite sequence (ordered list) of elements. It's true in mathematics, [relational databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751264/what-does-the-term-tuple-mean-in-relational-databases) and many languages (e.g. [C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), Prolog, [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple)...).

So `tuple` could be a good name.

[`node`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28computer_science%29) is an alternative since an object of the form `{prev, curr, next}` remembers of a node of a doubly linked list.

Comment: +1 for `node`, which is most likely the intended usage of this data-structure.

Answer (score -3):

Well this seems like a theory question on algorithms and datastructures.
As for the datastructure, if you want to return the three results at once, of course you need to put them into one datastructure, and of course that would make it a triple. 
Without a given syntax it's hard to give an answer and the question seems not properly stated, I feel the question is also how to calculate previous and next, and for this I would say something like:

```
curry = this;
prev = this;
next = this;
prev —-;
next++;

if(pre <0) prev = undefined;
if (next >= length) next = undefined;
```

As for the name of this kind of itertor, well as you already did I would call it triple or triplet, as it needs to store 3 values.

Comment: I think OP is asking for the *name* of this type of iterator, not how to *implement* one.